# How to query a Google Cloud SQL Database and display results as html?

Tags: sql, google-cloud-platform, html

I have a Google Cloud SQL Database. I want to run a static SQL query on the database and display results as html page without using a third party web server.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You can query your Cloud SQL database just like you would any MySQL database. you just need to make sure you tell Cloud SQL the IP from which you're going to connect:

[image: Cloud SQL Connectivity]

or configure your Cloud SQL instance to use a static IP, more about that [here](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/configure-ip).

Then you connect as per normal (this is some PHP taken from [here](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select.asp)):

```
$servername = "<The IP address from the overview page of Cloud SQL>";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "myDB";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "SELECT id, firstname, lastname FROM MyGuests";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
```

Comment: But where to write this php code? Do I need to create an App Engine instance just to display a few html pages?

Comment: Does the page need to be accessible from the web, or just for you on your machine?

Comment: Yes, it's required to be accessible from the web

Comment: Then yes, you need a web server. You can create a free Node.js app using this example: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/nodejs/building-app/